# "I was" and "I were" in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

I am not sure whether this sentence is correct:

> Since you **was** not online today, I assume you **were** not able to make it
>   on time.

In the first half of the sentence, I would replace "was" for "were". However, I have the certainty he did not come online today, so I am not sure whether I should use "was" or "were".

Can you please help me?

Comment: "Was" is never appropriate with second person subjects...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Standard English, **were** is the only form used with **you**. "You was" is ungrammatical in Standard English.

You must be confused because you must have seen both "I was" and "I were". Now that is a separate story, which has to do with the so called irrealis.

> If I/he were a bird, I/he'd fly all day. //irrealis
>
> I/he was a very noisy child when I/he was young. //indicative mood.

However, with we/you/they, "were" is used in both cases

> If you were a bird, you'd fly all day.
>
> You were a very noisy child when you were young.

Do note that in certain non-standard dialects, notably the African American Vernacular English, "you was" is possible

> Yo, what's poppin'? Tell me why you was so angry with me yesterday.

Comment: Thank you very much, incredibly fast and detailed reply.

Comment: As you mentioned, I was confused as I was trying to apply the rules for the first person of the singular to the second person of the singular.